# How to obtain a new Pointer in Java?

Tags: java, c, pointers, jna

How can I call a method with this method signature in C from JNA?

```
int open_device(context *ctx, device **dev, int index);
```

The last two lines of the C method look like this:

```
*dev = pdev;
return 0;
```

That's the only use of `dev` in that method. That means that I have to pass a poiner to an empty pointer to the method, right? The method then fills the empty pointer with the address of a `device` object and I can pass the pointer to the device to other methods.

My question is: Is this the right way to do that? If it is, how do I allocate a new pointer from Java?

---

Based on the accepted answer, I did this:

```
Memory p = new Memory(Pointer.SIZE);
Memory p2 = new Memory(Pointer.SIZE);
p.setPointer(0, p2);
nativeLib.open_device(ctx, p, index);
return p2;
```

Comment: Just curious: did your updated code work for you? It seems as though you are setting `*p = p2` but then the C function would do `*p = pdev` thus overwriting the value.

Comment: @casablanca: Yes, I tested it, it works.

Comment: @thejh do you know how to handle the invalidMemoryAccess Exception created because of invalid memory addresses being pointed to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that the JNA [`Pointer`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html) class has `setPointer` and `getPointer` methods to allow for multiple indirection, and the [`Memory`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) class to actually "allocate" native objects. So you should be able to do something like: (I'm just guessing from the JNA docs, I've not tested this)

```
Pointer pDev = new Memory(Pointer.SIZE); // allocate space to hold a pointer value
// pass pDev to open_device
Pointer dev = pDev.getPointer(0);        // retrieve pointer stored at pDev
```

Comment: Ah, that `new Memory(Pointer.SIZE);` looks like it is what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even better answer. You may want to allocate (malloc etc) depending upon Java String length. Example below is unit test from JNA project.

```
public void testGetSetStringWithDefaultEncoding() throws Exception {
    final String ENCODING = Native.DEFAULT_ENCODING;
    String VALUE = getName();
    int size = VALUE.getBytes(ENCODING).length+1;
    Memory m = new Memory(size);
    m.setString(0, VALUE);
    assertEquals("Wrong decoded value", VALUE, m.getString(0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no pointers in Java, only references.

You cannot reassign a reference when you pass them to methods, because you pass them by value.  Everything is passed by value in Java.

You can rewrite this method to instantiate a new instance of the device and return that instead of an int.

Comment: @duffymo: I was talking about JNA Pointers: https://jna.dev.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html

Comment: It's possible to do this without JNA.  You just have to return the new reference to the Device object you instantiate instead of an int.

Comment: @duffymo: And how can I access a c library (libbla.so) using Java without this explicitly native stuff?

Comment: @duffymo: In Java, references *can* be null, and they can be re-assigned. You're thinking of C++. Also, when interacting with native code, it is common to use Java objects to represent native pointers.

Comment: You're right Andy, now I realize that I was thinking of C++.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @Andy - After thinking about it some more, I think I was mixing my languages during the discussion.  I know that Java references can be null and C++ cannot.  If the OP is trying to simulate pointers or references in C++ using Java those issues will have to be taken into consideration.  I didn't write it well.